# Uncaught ReferenceError: Mage is not defined

Tags: php, magento-1.7, e-commerce

I have been trying to transfer our files from the development site to the production. On the dev site everything is working perfectly but not on the production, I'm receiving this javascript error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Mage is not defined
```

I have been trying to search online for possible solutions, I have already checked system requirements as well to be sure that the requirements are complete on the production but everything there is ok. I would like to know if where this javascript library is being loaded on the magento code we are currently using magento 1.7.0.2 version.

Best,

Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

js/mage/cookies.js is not loading. It defines the Mage Javascript class.

See this line:

```
if (!window.Mage) var Mage = {};
```

Comment: Any idea *why* this wouldn't be loading?

Comment: Custom theme issues most likely. Check for a page.xml file in your custom theme and see if it's missing the include for that file. The line will look like this:

```<action method="addJs"><script>mage/cookies.js</script></action>```

People tend to override that file directly instead of making local.xml layout edits and it tends to cause problems like this. You could test temporarily turning off your theme and seeing if the issue persists.

Comment: Thanks, turns out it was a js / css caching issue.